# Right outer join seems to not work because of where clause filter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query, I need to modify it, so that it gives me the result for `originDocForCurrency.id = 68` if there is no matching for `commission.referenzid = 68`. I tried the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` `ON commission.referenzid = originDocForCurrency.id`, but it don't give results, if no record is found with `commission.referenzid = 68`.

```
SELECT
    commission.netto AS commissionNetValue,
    commission.r_art AS commissionDocClass,
    commission.waehrung AS commissionCurrency,
    currencies.usd_brief AS foreignCurrencyUSDAsk,
    currencies.usd_geld AS foreignCurrencyUSDBid,
    originDocForCurrency.r_art AS originDocForCurrencyDocClass,
    originDocForCurrency.poswert AS originDocForCurrencyCommission,
 (SELECT originDoc.poswert FROM [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDoc WHERE originDoc.id = 68) AS originDocCommission,
 (SELECT originDoc.r_art FROM [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDoc WHERE originDoc.id = 68) AS originDocClass,
 (SELECT originDoc.waehrung FROM [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDoc WHERE originDoc.id = 68) AS originDocCurrency
FROM
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS commission
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDocForCurrency
    ON commission.referenzid = originDocForCurrency.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[devisen] AS currencies
    ON currencies.datum = (
            SELECT TOP 1 fc.datum
            FROM [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[devisen] AS fc
            WHERE fc.datum <= originDocForCurrency.von
                AND fc.usd_brief IS NOT NULL AND fc.usd_brief > 0
                AND fc.usd_geld IS NOT NULL AND fc.usd_geld > 0
            ORDER BY fc.datum DESC
            )
WHERE
    originDocForCurrency.id = 68
    AND     
    ( commission.referenzid = 68
        AND commission.btyp = 7
        AND ( commission.storno <> 1 OR commission.storno IS NULL )
        AND ( commission.proforma <> 1 OR commission.proforma IS NULL ) )
    OR
    ( commission.referenzid = 68
        AND commission.btyp = 8
        AND ( commission.storno <> 1 OR commission.storno IS NULL )
        AND ( commission.proforma <> 1 OR commission.proforma IS NULL ) )
```

How can I modify the query, to get the desired result? Can I achieve the desired result maybe with a [`CASE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006242/using-case-in-t-sql-in-the-where-clause) in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: You're explictly restricting yourself in the `WHERE` clause to `commission.referenzid = 68`, so that's going to cause issues whatever you do in the `JOIN`.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson yes, I know.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN then LEFT JOIN? I've been writing T-SQL since ~1997 and that construct still makes my head hurt. Try to put the required tables first, then LEFT JOIN to everything else. It makes the logic easier to follow for anyone else looking at the code. IMHO.

Comment: +1,000,000 Aaron.  That and having field names that are ALL CAPS drives me crazy.  Why hurt yourself like that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simplify your query slightly you have basically the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS commission
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDocForCurrency
    ON commission.referenzid = originDocForCurrency.id
WHERE
    originDocForCurrency.id = 68
AND (commission.referenzid = 68 OR commission.referenzid = 68);
```

Where you have no match in `[src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf]` the column `commission.referenzid` will be NULL, meaning this condition:

```
AND (commission.referenzid = 68 OR commission.referenzid = 68);
```

will not be true for these rows (because `NULL = 68` evaluates to `NULL`). This effectively makes your `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` an `INNER JOIN`

I have never been a big fan of `RIGHT JOIN` especially when `LEFT JOIN` appears in the same query. I would rearrange the query to make all the outer joins left outer joins for continuity purposes:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDocForCurrency
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS commission
    ON commission.referenzid = originDocForCurrency.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[devisen] AS currencies
    ON currencies.datum = (
            SELECT TOP 1 fc.datum
            FROM [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[devisen] AS fc
            WHERE fc.datum <= originDocForCurrency.von
                AND fc.usd_brief IS NOT NULL AND fc.usd_brief > 0
                AND fc.usd_geld IS NOT NULL AND fc.usd_geld > 0
            ORDER BY fc.datum DESC
            )
WHERE
    originDocForCurrency.id = 68
AND (commission.referenzid = 68 OR commission.referenzid = 68);
```

This does not solve the problem though since you still have the possibility of `commission.referenzid` being `NULL` and turning the LEFT OUTER JOIN into an INNER JOIN. You can get around this by moving the predicates to the JOIN conditiion:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDocForCurrency
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS commission
    ON commission.referenzid = originDocForCurrency.id
    AND     
    ( commission.referenzid = 68
        AND commission.btyp = 7
        AND ( commission.storno <> 1 OR commission.storno IS NULL )
        AND ( commission.proforma <> 1 OR commission.proforma IS NULL ) )
    OR
    ( commission.referenzid = 68
        AND commission.btyp = 8
        AND ( commission.storno <> 1 OR commission.storno IS NULL )
        AND ( commission.proforma <> 1 OR commission.proforma IS NULL ) 
    )
```

I am also fairly certain this condition can be simplified to:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDocForCurrency
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS commission
    ON commission.referenzid = originDocForCurrency.id
    AND commission.referenzid = 68
    AND commission.btyp in (7, 8)
    AND ISNULL(commission.storno, 0) <> 1
    AND ISNULL(commission.proforma, 0) <> 1
```

Making your final query:

```
SELECT
    commission.netto AS commissionNetValue,
    commission.r_art AS commissionDocClass,
    commission.waehrung AS commissionCurrency,
    currencies.usd_brief AS foreignCurrencyUSDAsk,
    currencies.usd_geld AS foreignCurrencyUSDBid,
    originDocForCurrency.r_art AS originDocForCurrencyDocClass,
    originDocForCurrency.poswert AS originDocForCurrencyCommission,
 (SELECT originDoc.poswert FROM [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDoc WHERE originDoc.id = 68) AS originDocCommission,
 (SELECT originDoc.r_art FROM [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDoc WHERE originDoc.id = 68) AS originDocClass,
 (SELECT originDoc.waehrung FROM [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDoc WHERE originDoc.id = 68) AS originDocCurrency
FROM
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDocForCurrency
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS commission
    ON commission.referenzid = originDocForCurrency.id
    AND commission.referenzid = 68
    AND commission.btyp in (7, 8)
    AND ISNULL(commission.storno, 0) <> 1
    AND ISNULL(commission.proforma, 0) <> 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[devisen] AS currencies
    ON currencies.datum = (
            SELECT TOP 1 fc.datum
            FROM [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[devisen] AS fc
            WHERE fc.datum <= originDocForCurrency.von
                AND fc.usd_brief IS NOT NULL AND fc.usd_brief > 0
                AND fc.usd_geld IS NOT NULL AND fc.usd_geld > 0
            ORDER BY fc.datum DESC
            )
WHERE
    originDocForCurrency.id = 68;
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

As pointed out in a comment, you don't need the three subselects, you can just use the columns in the table aliased `originDocForCurrency`:

```
SELECT
    commission.netto AS commissionNetValue,
    commission.r_art AS commissionDocClass,
    commission.waehrung AS commissionCurrency,
    currencies.usd_brief AS foreignCurrencyUSDAsk,
    currencies.usd_geld AS foreignCurrencyUSDBid,
    originDocForCurrency.r_art AS originDocForCurrencyDocClass,
    originDocForCurrency.poswert AS originDocForCurrencyCommission,
    originDocForCurrency.poswert AS originDocCommission,
    originDocForCurrency.r_art AS originDocClass,
    originDocForCurrency.waehrung AS originDocCurrency
FROM
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS originDocForCurrency
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[tckopf] AS commission
    ON commission.referenzid = originDocForCurrency.id
    AND commission.btyp in (7, 8)
    AND ISNULL(commission.storno, 0) <> 1
    AND ISNULL(commission.proforma, 0) <> 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[devisen] AS currencies
    ON currencies.datum = (
            SELECT TOP 1 fc.datum
            FROM [src_boss_entwicklung].[dbo].[devisen] AS fc
            WHERE fc.datum <= originDocForCurrency.von
                AND fc.usd_brief IS NOT NULL AND fc.usd_brief > 0
                AND fc.usd_geld IS NOT NULL AND fc.usd_geld > 0
            ORDER BY fc.datum DESC
            )
WHERE
    originDocForCurrency.id = 68;
```

Comment: The three subselects in the `SELECT` list can probably be removed as well - and replaced with simple columns.